# Angular standalone component's providers not working or not applied

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-providers, angular-standalone-components

I have a standalone component and I'd like to open a modal from in it (which is another standalone component but it is not matter now I guess).

I want to apply global rules for the material dialog, so I provide it in my component's provider. But it is not working.

The `SummaryComponent` looks like this:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
    DialogPosition,
    MatDialog,
    MatDialogConfig,
    MatDialogModule,
    MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { matDialogGlobalConfig } from 'src/app/utils/mat-dialog';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal-modal/modal-modal.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-summary',
    templateUrl: './summary.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./summary.component.scss'],
    standalone: true,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    imports: [CommonModule, MatDialogModule],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
            useValue: <MatDialogConfig>{ matDialogGlobalConfig },
        },
    ],
})
export class SummaryComponent {
    constructor(private matDialog: MatDialog) {}

    protected onInfoClicked(): void {
        this.matDialog.open(ModalComponent, <MatDialogConfig>{
            panelClass: 'rounded-modal',
            width: '100vw',
            position: <DialogPosition>{
                bottom: '0',
            },
        });
    }
}
```

The `ModalComponent` I want to open looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-modal',
    templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./modal.component.scss'],
    standalone: true,
})
export class ModalComponent {}
```

The `matDialogGlobalConfig` object contains 2 rules I want to apply as a global config:

```
export const matDialogGlobalConfig: MatDialogConfig = {
    backdropClass: 'custom-modal-dark-background',
    autoFocus: false,
};
```

If I put my global config into an "old" NgModule' providers everything works like a charm (even if the `SummaryComponent` is not part of it, wtf).

I have the same problem with material Snackbars, but I do not have any problems with pipes for example.

**Result of this code:** The `<MatDialogConfig>` rules provided in `onInfoClicked()` are applied, but the `matDialogGlobalConfig` are not.

Am I wrong or is that a known issue?

*Angular version: 15.1.3

Comment: I'm not prety sure, but... has you try add in imports array of the SummaryComponent the "ModalComponent": `imports: [CommonModule, MatDialogModule,ModalComponent]`?

Comment: @Eliseo, unfortunately this was not the problem.

Comment: Looks like you are providing the injection token but you are actually never injecting it, so it is provided but never used.

Comment: @Jordi Riera, how?

Comment: `constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS) options:MatDialogConfig)`

Answer (score 0):

Building on [@Jordi Riera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7649439/jordi-riera)'s comment
to your problem, instead of:

```
@Component({
    …,
    providers: [
        {
            provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
            useValue: <MatDialogConfig>{ matDialogGlobalConfig },
        },
    ],
})
export class SummaryComponent {
    constructor(private matDialog: MatDialog) {}

    protected onInfoClicked(): void {
        this.matDialog.open(ModalComponent, <MatDialogConfig>{
            panelClass: 'rounded-modal',
            width: '100vw',
            position: <DialogPosition>{
                bottom: '0',
            },
        });
    }
}
```

it should probably more look like:

```
@Component({
    …,
    providers: [
        {
            provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
            useValue: matDialogGlobalConfig,
        },
    ],
})
export class SummaryComponent {
    constructor(
        private matDialog: MatDialog,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS) private defaultOptions: MatDialogConfig
    ) {}

    protected onInfoClicked(): void {
        this.matDialog.open(ModalComponent,
        {
            ...defaultOptions,
            panelClass: 'rounded-modal',
            width: '100vw',
            position: {
                bottom: '0'
            },
        });
    }
}
```

(using spread syntax to merge `defaultOptions` and local overrides; and the type
assertions have been dropped, they only act as a switch-off for the type checker;
that's usually not desirable.)

(I don't have enough code to run this through a compiler, so this may not work
out-of-the box, but the idea should be clear.)

Of course, due to the limited scope of [node injector](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#dependency-injection-and-injectors-hierarchy)s, this only helps to lift
the `MatDialogConfig` value assignment from the class body to the annotation, but
does not make it available globally. I think for Angular 15+, the so-called
[environment injectors](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#environment-injectors)
encompass the available options to define your `MatDialogConfig` globally,
or at least in a larger scope.

PS: Your example used a lot of type assertions; as others pointed out elsewhere, this disables
proper type checking, and is probably not what you want. See e.g. https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/stop-misusing-typescript-type-assertions (he is a really helpful guy from around the NgRx community). In particular `<MatDialogConfig>{ matDialogGlobalConfig }` will not result in the value you most probably expected, this is an ES6 shorthand notation, its actual result hidden from the type checker by the type assertion.

Comment: Ty for your answer.
I've read the "Dependency injection and injectors hierarchy" topic carefully. If I understand what you and the documentation say, there is a difference between the the 2 types of providers.

If I provide something with the module injector so I can reach and use it in all of my components declared in my module OR app-wide (if it is provided in root). Clear.
If I provide something in my component's provider, I can reach and use it only in my component. Clear as dark.

But my problem is that I can't even access it in my own component...
I'll try this EnvironmentInjector

Comment: I'll keep you updated.

Comment: I thought about adding another answer to that problem, but stack overflow told me to better rewrite my existing answer... so I rewrote it XD. Hope it does not add confusion.